# How to access lists elements particular digits in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

```
str1= ",".join(str(e) for e in paths)
str2= ",".join(str(e) for e in newlist)
print(str1)
print(str2) 
for j in str2:
    for i in str1:
        if (j[0]==i[0]): 
        print('number is {}'.format(i))
```

Hey, I was making program where I needed to to access lists elements particular digits like if one list is [12,23,34] and another is [13,34],I want to access the first elements i.e 12's digits i.e 1 & 2 and compare it with another list and if any equal digit occurs i want to print the first element of the first list.
Like in our example 12 & 13 have 1 as equal digit I want to print 12.I am trying it from several days but getting stuck.And also I tried converting it in string then also some problem arised.

In the above example I am getting the particular digits printed like this:

```
number is 1
number is 3
number is 3
number is ,
number is ,
number is 1
number is 4
```

I dont want the 'comma' ,and if a match occurs the number should be printed as mentioned in the example.Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you only comparing the same indices or comparing each item in first list with all items in the second list?

Comment: What do u expect the output for:
l1 = [12,23,34], l2=[13,34]

res = ?  This will give some more insight on problem understanding.

Comment: Also, in your example '12' from first list and '13' from second list has the same first digit. If first digit is not same but second (or any further) digit is same, what result do you expect? for example '12' and '32'.

Comment: Your question needs a lot more details.
- Do you only compare the numbers in their place values? "ones, tens, hundreds" and so on
- Do you need to support bigger integers as well or only the range 10 -> 99?

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't keeping them as lists be easier to work with?
If you only want to compare the same indexes, then:

```
In []:
l1 = [12,23,34]
l2 = [13,34]
for a, b in zip(l1, l2):
    if a//10 == b//10:
        print(a)

Out[]:
12
```

Or you want to check any index:

```
In []:
import itertools as it

l1 = [12,23,34]
l2 = [13,34]
for a, b in it.product(l1, l2):
    if a//10 == b//10:
        print(a)

Out[]:
12
34
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
str1= ",".join(str(e) for e in paths)
str2= ",".join(str(e) for e in newlist)
print(str1)
print(str2) 
for j in str2:
    for i in str1:
        if (j[0]==i[0] and (i and j != ',')): 
        print('number is {}'.format(i))
```

output

```
12,23,34
13,34
number is 1
number is 3
number is 3
number is 3
number is 3
number is 4
```

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for solving my comma problem but I also want to get that particular number like when 12 & 13 are compared and a match of 1 occurs I want the number to be returned i.e 13.Any solution for this?

Comment: just print j @tester

Answer (score 0):

This should work for your use-case

```
list1 = [123, 12, 32232, 1231]
list2 = [1232, 23243, 54545]

def find_intersection(list1, list2):
    list2_digits = set.union(*[get_digits(x) for x in list2])
    for num1 in list1:
        digits1 = get_digits(num1)
        for num2 in list2:
            digits2 = get_digits(num2)
            if digits1.intersection(digits2):
                print 'Found Match', num1, num2  # We found a match
                # Break here unless you want to find all possible matches

def get_digits(num):
    d = set()
    while num > 0:
        d.add(num % 10)
        num = num / 10
    return d

find_intersection(list1, list2)
```

Comment: There's room for optimization here; the solution below by `AChampion` using itertools might be faster.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I totally understand the question, however:

```
list1 = [13,23,34]
list2 = [24,18,91]
list1 = list(map(str,list1)) #Map the arrays of ints to arrays of strings
list2 = list(map(str,list2))

for j in list1:
    for i in list2:
        for character in j:
            if character in i:
                print(j+' matches with '+i)
                break
```

Prints out:

```
13 matches with 18
13 matches with 91
23 matches with 24
34 matches with 24
```